# Reading sqlite raw data into QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qstring, qbytearray

I have a qsqlite which has a column contains raw data.

The codes

```
QByteArray data= query.value("data").toString().toLatin1();
```

or

```
QByteArray data= query.value("data").toByteArray();
```

give the exact same results which are correct except for some values. Certain bytes in the original data ara being converted into 0x3F. (I think values greater then a certain value)

The code below gives a result beyond far the real data.

```
data= query.value("data").toString().toUtf8()
```

What is the thing I'm missing?

--- Edit (example data has been added)

Real raw data in sqlite :

01 a4 81 1c 20 02 00 ff

```
query.value("data").toString().toByteArray()
```

gives:

01 a4 81 1c 20 02 00 3f

```
query.value("data").toString().toUtf8()
```

gives:

01 c2 a4 c2 81 1c 20 02 00 ef bf bd

By the way, the type of raw data I'm talking about is BLOB in sqlite database.

Comment: What do you mean, by *"The code below gives a result beyond far the real data. "*. Please add an [mcve].

Comment: I have added examples.

Comment: What does `query.value("data").toByteArray()` produce?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation of [QString::toLatin1()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1). It is undefined if the input string contains non-Latin1 characters. I guess this is the reason why certain values are replaced with 0x3f (which is '?' in ASCII).

Do you know if the raw data originally represented a character sequence in any encoding? Otherwise, I guess it doesn't make much sense to convert the raw byte sequence into a specific string encoding. You could try and take a look at different [string encodings](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: I can read the data by python if I set connection text_factory to bytes. The problem with Qt I cannot find a way to do the same thing. Qt insists on geting BLOB as QString not as byteArray. By the way, raw data doesn't represent a string in any encoding. It's just raw data.